# Can I execute procedure after select?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to make a script, which will verify my stored procedure's function. However, once I put execute store procedure there, I get this kind of error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NEW_PRODUCT" when expecting one of the following:
   := . ( @ % ; immediate
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "NEW_PRODUCT" to continue.

My script looks like this:

```
DECLARE
  id_unit number;
  id_unit_old number;
  var_materialid number;
  var_processid number;
  serial_no varchar(30);
  product_name_new varchar(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT max(id) INTO id_unit_old
  FROM Unit;

  execute new_product('NTB', 'Diablo', 'CPU-I7', 'GPU-M800', 'RAM-K2');

  SELECT max(id) INTO id_unit
  FROM Unit;

  IF id_unit > id_unit_old THEN BEGIN 
    SELECT id_material, id_process, serial_number INTO var_materialid, var_processid, serial_no
    FROM Unit
    WHERE id = id_unit;

    SELECT name INTO product_name_new
    FROM Material
    WHERE id = var_materialid;
  ELSE
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002, 'Insert to table Unit has failed!');
  END IF;
END;
```

Any suggestions what is the problem and how can I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `execute` word right before the `new_product` word, when you call a PL/SQL procedure from another procedure or from PL/SQL anonymous block you must call it by its name.